# HttpServletResponse buffer clear

Tags: servlets, response

When we use forward, the forward method clears the response and then sends it to the other servlet. I want to do the same thing while using redirect.
Basically what is happening is:

1. I hit the url of page 1
2. in page 1 I have code which redirects me to page2
3. I get redirected to page 2 but page 1 appears momentarily on the screen (I want to avoid this)

I tried using `response.resetBuffer()` and `response.reset()` just before `response.sendRedirect()` but didn't help.
For some reason using redirect is necessary and I can't use forward.

Comment: *"I get redirected to page 2 but page 1 appears momentarily on the screen"* This is impossible. Committed response cannot be taken back at all. There's something else going on. Please show an SSCCE which demonstrates your concrete problem.

Comment: hey ya I checked and what you are saying is right if I use jsp's and servlets .... I was trying the above using ZK will explore it further and will get back to you
thanks :)

Comment: Why didn't you tell in first place that you were using ZK?

Comment: i thought that the question I had written had nothing to do with zk :)